# Graphics not rendering/adding ARCGIS JSAPI version 4.12

Tags: arcgis-js-api

For some users of an application I built using ARCGIS JSAPI version 4.12, no graphics appear on maps.  The issue does not seem to be browser specific (some users with identical browser versions experienced the issue, others did not) , but does seem to be new to version 4.12 of the API.  Are there known causes of this?  Some browser or account-level setting perhaps?

I have attached two screenshots from a computer experiencing the issue - one of ESRI's "Intro to Graphics"  tutorial page that should show graphics but doesn't, and the second of the Codepen linked from that page, changed to version 4.11, which does show  the intended graphics.

[image: Tutorial Page]

[image: Codepen Page with Version Change]

Comment: Although the problem does seem to occur in multiple browsers, the above screenshots are from Chrome 72.0.3626.121

Comment: Hi, it looks like your screenshots are not working.

Answer (score 0):

I issue with same problem on my computer: Mozilla, Chrome, Opera; 
Map shows correctly, graphics are visible.

Client computer same browsers;
Map not showing graphics but layers are created. I can click where graphic should be and popup shows.

Also official graphics example is not working on client computer:

[Official example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=intro-graphics)

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO0EG.jpg)